# CloudConnect and GoogleBigQuery

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, gooddata, cloveretl, cloud-connect

I'm currently trying to do the OAuth process in GoodData's CloudConnect (also known as Clover ETL).

Does anyone have a guide or anything because the documentation is not clear on hot to set up OAuth 2.0 and i keep getting the error

```
bearer=Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have valid token? In CloudConnect you have to use auth token that is only valid for limited amount of time. Then you need to make another request with your refresh token to received your new auth token. The workflow is:

1. GET initial refresh and auth token and store them (done in first run only)

then for each BigQuery API request:

1. GET new auth token by request that includes refresh token
2. POST/GET with your refreshed token to the Google BigQuery API

Hope this helped! Feel free to download example here:

http://developer.gooddata.com/downloads/cloud-connect/examples/BigQuery.zip

Answer (score 0):

GoodData CloudConnect REST Connector has been updated and works with OAuth 2.0 natively. Check it out how it works here:

https://developer.gooddata.com/article/setting-up-oauth-2